# Solve $ye^{2x}dx = (4+e^{2x})dy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So my solution was:
$$\frac 1 2(\ln(4+e^{2x})) - \ln(y) = c$$
 but the correct solution $c^2y^2 = 4 + e^{2x}.$ How do you get that solution let alone the $c^2$? Thank you

Comment: You can rewrite your solution as $$\frac12 \ln (4+e^{2x})-\ln y=\ln c$$ instead.  Then this is equivalent to the version given by "the correct solution."

Comment: @Beat: Do you mean

$$\frac 1 2(\ln(4+e^{2x})) - \ln|y| = c?$$

When we separate the equation and solve, we need to take the absolute value of $y$ as we don't know if $y\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given

$$ye^{2x}\,dx = (4+e^{2x})\,dy \implies \frac{1}{y}\,dy=\frac{e^{2x}}{4+e^{2x}}\,dx$$

Let $u=e^{2x}$. Then, $e^{2x}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\,du$ and the equation becomes

$$\frac{1}{y}\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4+u}\,du$$

whereby integrating forms

$$\ln |y|= \frac{1}{2}\ln |4+u| +c_1$$

or

$$\ln |y|= \frac{1}{2}\ln \left(4+e^{2x}\right) +c_1$$

which rearranges to your solution

$$c_1=\ln |y|-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(4+e^{2x}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{4+e^{2x}}}\right)$$

so that taking the exponential forms

$$c_2=e^{\large{c_1}}= \frac{|y|}{\sqrt{4+e^{2x}}}\implies \sqrt{4+e^{2x}}=c_3|y|$$

therefore

$${c_3}^2y^2=4+e^{2x}$$

so both answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is perfectly correct:
$$\frac 1 2(\ln(4+e^{2x})) - \ln|y| = c$$
$$\ln(4+e^{2x}) - 2\ln|y| = C$$
$$\ln(4+e^{2x}) - \ln(y^2) = C$$
$$\ln \left( \frac {4+e^{2x}}{y^2} \right ) = C$$
Take the exponential
$$\dfrac {(4+e^{2x})} {y^2} = k$$
The result follow:
$$4+e^{2x} = ky^2$$

Comment: It's corrected now thanks @Axion004

Answer (score 0):

This can be rearranged to
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{ye^{2x}}{4+e^{2x}} \\
\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{e^{2x}dx}{4+e^{2x}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Which integrates to 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(y) =\frac{1}{2}  \ln(4+e^{2x}) - \ln(c) .
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(y) =\frac{1}{2}  \ln(4+e^{2x}) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(c) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Indeed you are free to choose the arbitrary constant & both answers are correct.

Comment: How can we write $\ln(y)$ when we don't know that $y>0$?